# Get JS Value for PHP URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a script that gets the value from the checked box client side like this:

```
var checkedValue = null; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
  if(inputElements[i].checked){
       checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
       break;
  }
}
```

Here is the check box:

```
<input id='cb10' name='answer[]' value='$correct' class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
```

Then I have php code to display the "next" button where i am url encoding variables that I need on the next page like this:

```
echo "<a href='idmatch_process.php? answer="+checkedValue+"&totalcorrect=". urlencode($totalcorrect)  ."&escalation=". urlencode($escalation) ."&correctrule=".  urlencode($correctrule) ."&page=" . $next_page ."'>Next</a>";
```

I need "answer" to equal the checked value but I can not seem to get it to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: You switched from using javascript concat `+` to PHP concatenation `.`

Comment: You'll have to update the href using js if you want it changed after page load.

Comment: you need js in your link... call a function on "onclick" of the next button. In this function you can check the value and redirect the page with window.location

Comment: As Michael Lane suggested in his answer, you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes if you only want one answer and just use the name "answer" for all the radio buttons. If you do this, you could skip the javascript by changing the anchor tag to a submit `input` button and wrapping everything in a form. You would also have the add the other php variables as values in hidden `input` elements

Answer (score 0):

Sinply assign a id to the anchor tag and do the following:

```
var vars = [], hash;
var url = document.getElementById('idOfYourAnchor').getAttribute('href');

var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
console.log(vars);
```

This will give you an array of all the variables and values of them, now you change the value of your checkbox and build a new url for the anchor.